# iterate through each split in several columns in python

Tags: python

I have some coordinates like so:

```
Coordinates_location   Coordinates_degree             Coordinates_job
29.75, -95.36          29.75, -95.36                 29.75, 95.36; 29.75, -95.36
32.77, -96.79          30.72, -95.55                 32.7762719, -96.79
29.75, -95.36          30.44, -91.18; 33.18, -97.14  29.75, -95.36; 29.97, -90.07; 29.75, -95.36; 29.75, -95.36
```

Where coordinates_degree and coordinates_job can have multiple coordinates in the same column delimited by semicolon.

I am trying to calculate the distance between all coordinates so I need to iterate through each row to calculate each possible coordinate combination for each row. For example for the third row, I would calculate something like:

```
29.75, -95.36 - 30.44, -91.18
29.75, -95.36 - 33.18, -97.14
29.75, -95.36 - 29.75, -95.36
29.75, -95.36 - 29.97, -90.07
29.75, -95.36 - 29.75, -95.36
29.75, -95.36 - 29.75, -95.36
30.44, -91.18 - 33.18, -97.14
30.44, -91.18 - 29.75, -95.36
30.44, -91.18 - 29.97, -90.07
30.44, -91.18 - 29.75, -95.36
```

and so on until I get all the possible combinations.

My first thought was to split column for degree and job first then go through the original column a, split_b, split_c but it's not doing what I think it's doing so the geodesic calculation is giving errors. I also feel like this is not the proper or best way to do this and there has to be a better way.

```
for a, b,c in all_coordinates.itertuples(index=False):
  for s, sp in zip(b.split(';'), c.split(';')):
      splitb.append(s)
      splitc.append(sp)
  for z, x, y in zip(a, splitb, splitc):
      total_distance.append(geodesic(z, x))
      total_distance.append(geodesic(x, y))
      total_distance.append(geodesic(z, y))
```

How can I calculate each combination of coordinates for each row?

Comment: hello, the zip function after the split may not always be able to pick all the coordinates.   The only time it'd be able to pick all coordinates is when the column Coordinates_degree and the column Coordinates_job contain the same number of coordinates.  For example if one of them has two coordinates and the other one three, only the first two would make it's way in the output of zip().

Note, the same is also true for the second zip() - it will drop every other coordinate after the first one because the column Coordinates_location  only has one coordiante.

Comment: May I suggest putting all coordinates on a row into a single list and then using itertools.combinations() on it to extract two at a time?   Once that's done you can iterate one more time over those combinations to create the total_distance list.

Comment: @SGandhi implementing it into using itertools.combinations() so that now each row is (coordinate_set1; coordinate_set2) wouldn't it run into almost the same problem? I still need to do a for loop and split at semicolon in each row to feed it into the geodesic distance api like geodesic(coordinate_set1, coordinate_set2).

Comment: @JesperExra - can you not append them into a single list?   Instead of coordinate_set1 and coordinate_set2?   If all coordinates are in a universal list for each row, all you'd need to do us use itertools.combinations() to return all sets / tuples containing two of them.

Comment: just put together a code snipped to illustrate the approach - revised it again this morning to get rid of the zips.   I haven't REPLed this so there could be syntax errors. wud love to hear if you were able to use it in some shape or form.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Define a single list for storing coordintes
all_coordinates = []

for a, b, c in all_coordinates.itertuples(index=False):
  all_coordinates.append(a)      # Append coordinate from col a

  for s in b.split(';'):
      all_coordinates.append(s)  # Append coordinates from col b
  for sp in c.split(';'):    
      all_coordinates.append(sp) # Append coordinates from col c

  # Use itertools.combinations to get all unique combinations of coordinates as tuples
  for tuple in itertools.combinations(all_coordinates):
      total_distance.append(geodesic(*tuple))   # Unpack tuple and pass to your function
```